# Unable to run java jar command on target machine in Ansible

Tags: java, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run the following command:

```
java -jar jar-from-application.jar --file myown.properties
```

Couple of problems I faced earlier while trying to run this on target machine. Tomcat needs to be running and a war file needs to be deployed completely before I run the above command. This is what I did to insure that pre conditions are met. For Tomcat:

```
nohup startup.sh
```

and then check for deployed file bu using curl to check for status 200:

```
- name: Check if URL is available
  shell: curl --head --silent http://target-mchine:8080/restoftheurl
  register: result
  until: result.stdout.find("200 OK") != -1
  retries: 12
  delay: 10
```

It does above two steps correctly but when the next task is to run the

```
java -jar jar-from-application.jar --file myown.properties
```

it for some reason says that it cannot read the properties file. However, if I run the same jar command on the remote machine locally, then it works perfectly. I even added some wait time after successful execution of curl command, just in case, but it doesn't make any difference. I tried doing the following too:

```
nohup java -jar jar-from-application.jar --file myown.properties
```

as it was suggested online but that didn't make any difference either. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Try fully qualifying the path to the properties file. `--file /path/to/myown.properties`, also check to be sure the permissions are correct.

Comment: I did chdir as suggested by @Henrik Pingel but I tried doing your absolute path and that worked too. It was trying to read some other file instead of the one that I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you set the correct `path` to the properties file in the command by using the `chdir` argument of the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html#options) or set the full path in the command.